# Why Sceneform 1.17.1 displays only audio and not video corectly?

Tags: java, android, arcore, sceneform

I am creating an AR app using Sceneform, and no matter what I have tried this far Sceneform doesn't display a video correctly over an image. This is the result I get when the camera detects the image:
[The Video Image that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWLh3.png)

Here is the code I have on the corresponding class:

texture = new ExternalTexture();

```
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.video);
    mediaPlayer.setSurface(texture.getSurface());
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

    ModelRenderable
            .builder()
            .setSource(this, Uri.parse("video_screen.sfb"))
            .build()
            .thenAccept(modelRenderable -> {
                renderable = modelRenderable;
                modelRenderable.getMaterial().setExternalTexture("videoTexture",
                        texture);
                modelRenderable.getMaterial().setFloat4("keyColor",
                        new Color(0.01843f, 1f, 0.098f));
            })
            .exceptionally(
                    throwable -> {
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to load video renderable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        toast.show();
                        return null;
                    });


    arFragment = (com.stratos.syrostownhall.CustomArFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.arFragment);

    if (arFragment != null) {
        scene = arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene();
    }

    scene.addOnUpdateListener(this::onUpdate);

}

private void onUpdate(FrameTime frameTime) {

    if (isImageDetected)
        return;

    Frame frame = arFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();

    Collection<AugmentedImage> augmentedImages =
            frame != null ? frame.getUpdatedTrackables(AugmentedImage.class) : null;


    for (AugmentedImage painting : Objects.requireNonNull(augmentedImages)) {
        if (painting.getTrackingState() == TrackingState.TRACKING) {

            if (painting.getName().equals("painting")) {

                isImageDetected = true;

                playVideo(painting.createAnchor(painting.getCenterPose()), painting.getExtentX(),
                        painting.getExtentZ());

                break;
            }

        }
    }

}

private void playVideo(Anchor anchor, float extentX, float extentZ) {

    mediaPlayer.start();

    AnchorNode anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);

    texture.getSurfaceTexture().setOnFrameAvailableListener(surfaceTexture -> {
        anchorNode.setRenderable(renderable);
        texture.getSurfaceTexture().setOnFrameAvailableListener(null);
    });

    anchorNode.setWorldScale(new Vector3(extentX, 1f, extentZ));

    scene.addChild(anchorNode);

}
```

Also, I add the asset manually using the following syntax:

```
sceneform.asset ('sampledata/video_screen.obj',
        'default',
        'sampledata/video_screen.sfa',
        'src/main/assets/video_screen')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the `video_screen.sfb` file.

If anyone else is facing the same issue try using the following video_screen file:

https://github.com/heyletscode/Play-Video-On-Augmented-Image/blob/master/Project/app/src/main/assets/video_screen.sfb